# Visual Studio 2017: How to make intellisense accept friend conversion constructor from other class?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, intellisense, friend-function

I am following a book with chapter about conversions from 2008. Compiling on visual studio 2017 C++ project.

In the book there was an example on the use of conversion constructor where classes "complex" and "number" exist and "number" can be converted into "complex" through the use of constructor where class "number" befriends the constructor of class "complex" to let it use "number" private properties (as much as I understand).

And the code sample from the book (copied word to word) makes intellisense not happy as it doesn't see friend "complex(number)" constructor and I do not know why.

Code is as below:

```
#include <string>

class number;
class complex;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

class complex
{
private:
    double real;
    double imaginary;
public:
    complex(double r = 0, double i = 0) : real(r), imaginary(i) {}
    complex(number);
};

class number
{
    double n;
    std::string description;

    //friend complex::complex(number); // finds no instance of overload of function complex::complex

public:
    number(int k, std::string t = "no description") : n(k), description(t) {}
};

complex::complex(number ob)
{
    //real = ob.n;  //no friend, no access to private property
    imaginary = 0;
}
```

My question is, why is "friend complex::complex(number);" not visible by intellisense ?

Image of error from the IDE
[image: image of IDE error]

Comment: What compiler are you using? [Can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t97nQFeXyFTz2mYL) the issue.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fad7d94cf5494717

Comment: Not sure how to read exact compiler name but I compile using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @klarentbass Did you actually try to compile the code? Since you are not showing a compilation error, but rather an intellisense error..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Quite shameful I did not think of it, it compiles and [builds correctly](https://imgur.com/a/tb0BcWs). I confused intellisense with compilation. Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to be something about intellisense? Like, is this a bug in intellisense? Or, how to make intellisense happy?

Comment: @jxh Edited, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this as a bug in [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) itself. But you can work around it by hiding the code in question. For example,

```
#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__
    #define INTELLIHIDE(...) // Hide from IntelliSense
#else
    #define INTELLIHIDE(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif
```

So, then you could do this:

```
    INTELLIHIDE(friend complex::complex(number);)
```

And also,

```
complex::complex(number ob)
{
    INTELLIHIDE(real = ob.n;)
    imaginary = 0;
}
```